# Continue executing loop after catching an exception in try/catch

Tags: java, while-loop, try-catch

Once an exception is caught in this code, the `menuSystem` method is run, but once I go to input a number the programme closes and the "Build is successful" message is displayed. Is there any way to get back into the while loop once an exception has occured?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   final UnitResults myUnit = new UnitResults(10, "Java");
   int option = menuSystem();

   try {
      while (option != 0) {
         final Scanner keyb = new Scanner(System.in);
         System.out.println("");
         switch (option) {
         }
      }
   } catch (Exception InputMismachException) {
      System.out.println("\nPlease Enter a Valid Number\n");
      option = menuSystem();
   }
}
```

Comment: You want to put the try/catch within the while loop

Comment: Please format your code better when asking for help on a public forum.

Comment: If you indent your code properly, you won't need those redundant `//end loop`, `//end switch`, etc. comments.

Comment: Edit : try catch wasent within the loop *Facepalm* thanks for the help

Answer (score 18, accepted):

put your **try/catch** inside your **while loop**:

```
    while (option != 0) {
        final Scanner keyb = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("");
        try {
            switch (option) {

            }
        } catch (Exception InputMismachException) {
            System.out.println("\nPlease Enter a Valid Number\n");
            option = menuSystem();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I learned something new today. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Put the `try` and `catch` within the `while` loop. If the code is using `nextInt()` then you need to skip the invalid input as it will not be consumed in the event of a mismatch.

It would be possible to avoid the exception handling for `InputMismatchException` by using the `hasNextInt()` methods of `Scanner` until a valid input is entered before attempting to consume it:

```
while (!kb.hasNextInt()) kb.next();
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way you can do it:

```
   List<File> directories;
   ...
   for ( File f : directories ) {
        try {
            processFolder(f);
        } catch( Exception e ) {
            SimpleLog.write(e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I know this is an older question but could you elaborate on what the `continue` is supposed to do in this case?

Comment: Sorry, continue is implied.  It will continue through the loop anyway.