# Using Try/Catch Block to Identify Strings in File

Tags: java, file-io, try-catch, java.util.scanner, inputmismatchexception

I am attempting to read a bunch of numbers from a file and add them up. But I have added a few Strings in the File also. I am now trying to read the numbers add them together and using the try/catch block I am trying to display an error when the file reads a string instead of a integer. However as soon as the code reads a string from the file it gives me the error, the code does not continue to add the numbers together. It simply prints the error and prints 0. How do I modify it so that it continues to read the numbers and add them together as well as display an Error message after it reads a string.

Code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class AddNumbers {

public static void main (String[]args) {
    try{
        File myFile = new File("numbers.txt");
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(myFile);

        int x;
        int y = 0;
        try{
            //Read file while it has a line 
            while(scan.hasNextLine()){
            //scan a integer value
                x = scan.nextInt();
            //Add the scanned value to y
                y = y+x;
            }
        }catch(InputMismatchException e){
            //If a string is found then print this error
            System.err.println("Strings found! Error!");
        }
        System.out.println(y);
        scan.close();

    }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
        System.err.println("No such file exists!");
        System.out.println();
    }


}

}
```

File Contents

```
Albert 
10000
20000
30000
Ben 
50000
12000
Charlie
```

Comment: just add the try-catch block inside the while instead of what you're doing

Comment: Add a try catch around x = scan.nextInt(); so that the loop continues

Comment: Your answer can be found here: [Continue executing loop after catching an exception in try/catch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13805008/continue-executing-loop-after-catching-an-exception-in-try-catch)

Comment: that gives infinite loop displaying error message

Comment: @Trobbins why a simple comment instead of a duplicate flag?

Comment: @RealSkeptic I generally do both. :)

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, the `try-catch` block is placed outside the `while` loop. In case an exception occurs, control reaches the `catch` block which prints the error message, and then exits the loop. You need to place the `try-catch` inside the loop.

Secondly, when `Scanner#nextInt()` throws an exception, the `Scanner` would not consume the input, causing an infinite loop in case an invalid integer is read. You can simply read the whole line using `Scanner#nextLine()` and parse it as an `int`:

```
while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
    try {
        // scan a integer value
        String line = scan.nextLine();
        x = Integer.parseInt(line);
        // Add the scanned value to y
        y = y + x;
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) { // this can be thrown by Integer.parseInt(line)
        // If a string is found then print this error
        System.err.println("Strings found! Error!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try reading the line as a string and then using `Integer.parseInt(x)` and catching that if it throws an exception.

See [Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String)) for information about `Integer.parseInt()`

Comment: The question is about continuing the loop should an exception be thrown

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the try/catch inside the while loop.

```
While(scan.hasNextLine()){
    try{
      x=scan.nextInt();
      // add
    }catch(InputMismatchException ime){
       //write error
    }
}
```